# How to update cluster source on wfs source

Tags: openlayers-3

I do have a wfs source and a cluster source in a vector layer. From time to time I know that something changed in the serverside wfs source, so I want to update the vector layer to show the new features. How can I trigger an update of the wfs layer without interaction of the user (especially change resolution)? 
An `clear()` on the cluster source or the vector source or any combination of it did not help. Also a `changed()` or a `map.render()` did not work.
I would like to trigger somehow the loader-function of the vector source.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to a known issue: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3917

I'd suggest using the change from the pull request above in a custom build, which should enable you to reload the layer (and the cluster) by calling clear on the base source.

Alternatively, you could initialize a new cluster source each time you call clear on the base source, and replace the cluster source by calling setSource on the layer.